# What makes the Thread.activeCount() print the "wrong" number?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

So i'm doing a little project to understand how Threads work. And i think i'm just about to get the hang of it. There is just one little problem that keeps me frustrated since i don't get reason behind it happening. Here it comes.

I really dont get why the Thread.activeCount() method outputs 3 when i only create a single thread inside the Main method. Can someone please explain what i am overseeing?

```
public class Main implements Runnable{

    private int threadsAlive = 0;
    private static int priority = 5; //Default
    private String threadName;
    private Thread t1;

    public Main(String threadName){ //Constructor
        this.threadName = threadName;
        System.out.println("Creating thread: " + threadName);
    }

    public void start(){ //Starting the thread
        System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName);
        if (t1 == null) {
            t1 = new Thread (this, threadName);
            t1.start ();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() { //Running the thread
        System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
        aliveCount(true);
        System.out.println("^According to the activeCount method: "+ Thread.activeCount()); // Why is this 3?

        try {
            Thread.sleep(750);
            System.out.println("Lets sleep for a while ...zZZZ");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Im awake! But not for long :(");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
        aliveCount(false);
    }

    private void aliveCount(boolean up) {
        if (up) {
            threadsAlive++;
        } else {
            threadsAlive--;
        }
        System.out.println("Threads alive: " + threadsAlive);

        if (threadsAlive == 0) {
            System.out.println("No threads is alive.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { //Running threads
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a name for the thread.");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("A thread with the name: " + name + " is saved for creation.");

        System.out.println("Please enter the priority level for the thread.");
        priority = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("A thread with the priority level of: " + priority + " is saved for creation");

        System.out.println("*****************************************************");

        Main obj = new Main(name);
        obj.start();

        System.out.println("Setting the priority of " + name +" thread to " + priority);
        setPriority(priority);
        System.out.println("Priority is now set to: " + priority + " successfully");
    }

    public static void setPriority(int priority) {
        Main.priority = priority;
    }
}
```

**The output:**

```
Please enter a name for the thread.
t1
A thread with the name: t1 is saved for creation.
Please enter the priority level for the thread.
10
A thread with the priority level of: 10 is saved for creation
*****************************************************
Creating thread: t1
Starting t1
Running t1
Threads alive: 1
^According to the activeCount method: 3
Setting the priority of t1 thread to 10
Priority is now set to: 10 successfully
Lets sleep for a while ...zZZZ
Im awake! But not for long :(
Thread t1 exiting.
Threads alive: 0
No threads is alive.
```

Comment: Main thread, your thread created with `new Thread`, signal dispatcher thread.

Comment: @Michael Ah! Makes sense, thank you for your time! :)

Comment: The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#activeCount()) says:  *"Returns an estimate of the number of active threads in the current thread's thread group and its subgroups. Recursively iterates over all subgroups in the current thread's thread group.

The value returned **is only an estimate** because the number of threads may change dynamically while this method traverses internal data structures, **and might be affected by the presence of certain system threads**. "*